# No se guardan los datos en la lista

Tags: c#, clase

Estoy trabajando con un programa que simula un cajero bancario y que permita agregar personas (los datos, se borran al momento de cerrar la consola). Trato de almacenar los datos en una clase *lista* pero no se me guardan.

```
public class Clientes
{
    public string Nombre;
    public string Apellido;
    public string Usuario;
    public int Pin;
    public int Balance;
}
public class MngClientes
{
    private List<Clientes> Gente = new List<Clientes>();

    public void AgregarClientes(Clientes Clin)
    {
        Gente.Add(Clin);
    }
    public int Todos()
    {
        return Gente.Count;
    }
    public List<Clientes> VerClientes()
    {
        return Gente;
    }
}
```

¿Cómo puedo resolverlo?

Comment: pero ¿tratas de que al cerrar la consola la información persista al volverla a abrir?

Comment: Puedes [editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/312978/edit) y agregar más detalles, como un ejemplo de cómo se usa y cuál es exactamente el objetivo. Así como está no se entiende mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Las listas son dinamicas esa es una ventaja pero trabajan como una memoria ram, los datos  son almacenados temporalmente